# noobslab/themes repository for Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: themes, repository, 16.10

Where can I find the repository for the newest version of Ubuntu?

```
add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
```

does not work, it results into error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~noobslab/ubuntu/themes'.
ERROR: '~noobslab' user or team does not exist.
```

What should I do?

Comment: It says the PPA is for "Xenial, Wily, Vivid, Utopic, Trusty, Saucy, Raring, Quantal, Precise, Oneiric, Natty, Maverick, and Lucid". There are no packages for Yakkety - 16.10 at the moment. It might, and might not, be related to that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ppa:noobslab/themes does not have any packages in it for Ubuntu 16.10. The latest published packages in ppa:noobslab/themes are for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Will it possibly have them in the future? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Most likely ppa:noobslab/themes will be updated eventually as it has packages for all releases from 10.04 to 16.04 already.

Answer (score 1):

Software and repository changes require sudo privileges, try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
```

I just tried that myself and it worked.  I'll have to try some of them out. :-)

Comment: I used it with sudo, of course.  I tried it right now again, still the same error. What version of Ubuntu do you run?

Comment: @DwayneHopkins it gives an error when doing `apt update` it's not setup for 16.10 yet